# One web application, two namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I have one web application with two projects:

Project "Website"

```
 Using CMS;

      namespace Web
      {

      }
```

Project "CMS"

```
 namespace CMS
 {
      public class Functions
      {
      }
 }
```

Then I want to be able to use `CMS.Functions.MyMethod()` inside Website.Web.

Im having some problem with this.. Inside the "Website" project I have added "CMS" as a reference and I have also added `Using CMS;` and even tho the intellisense picks up CMS.Functions I get an error! The word `CMS` gets underlined blue and I get the message:

> The name 'CMS' does not exist in the current context

What am I missing out? Its so weird becuase I can write `CMS.Functions` and the "Functions" part comes up in the intellisense but when I finish the line the word `CMS` gets underlined blue and I get the error even tho I got a reference and a Using statement.

Comment: When you hover over the blue-userlined CMS, what does the popup say? To troubleshoot you can open the DLL in the Object browser (right-click, open with) and see what it actually has.

Comment: Is this a web site, or a web application project? Created with "File->New Web Site", or "File->New Project"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sound of it, you want to make your Functions class methods to be static

```
namespace CMS
 {
      public class Functions
      {
         public static void MyMethod(){ 
             //do stuff
         }
      }
 }
```

Comment: He should probably also make `Functions` a static class as it seems like a helper class.

Comment: @ChrisWue true, and I would if it was my code, but I didn't want to assume about what the rest of his class was doing, could be an abstracted example :)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you have not added a reference to the CMS project to your main project. That is the only time that I get the exception about the name not existing in the current context.